# Why combination of hasPrevious() and add() in listiterator goes into infinite looping ,while hasNext() and add() doesn't?

Tags: java, collections, iterator

*ArrayList with two elements*

```
     ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>() { 
        {
            add("hai");
            add("hello");
        }
    };
```

*created a list iterator for that list*

```
   ListIterator l = a.listIterator();
```

*traversing using next and adding an element "bye" to the list*

```
   while (l.hasNext()) {              

        l.next();
        l.add("bye");

    }
    System.out.println(a);
```

**Output of above code is**= [hai,bye,hello,bye]

*traversing to last of the list*

```
    while(l.hasNext()) {             
        l.next();
    }
```

*traversing forwards using prev and adding an element "bye" to the list*

```
    while (l.hasPrevious()) {         

        l.previous();
        l.add("bye");

    }
    System.out.println(a);
```

**Goes Infinite and prints nothing!!!**

Comment: Is the last while loop independent of others? Or you run all the above code together?

Comment: @MohammedDeifallah the last two while loops will be executed a same time,because i have to traverse to the last to traverse forwards!

Comment: Please go through oracle docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#add(E)

Comment: @GowthamPrasath Then, in the last loop, what you're doing is that, as mentioned in the 1st answer, you turn to the position between the two last elements. Then you add another element. Then you turn again to the same position ... etc. It's an infinite loop.

Comment: @MohammedDeifallah i did the same using next() but i didn't end up in infinite loop,only previous() does that

Answer (score 4):

Well, the Javadoc of `ListIterator`'s `add` explains that:

> Inserts the specified element into the list (optional operation). The element is inserted immediately before the element that would be returned by next, if any, and after the element that would be returned by previous, if any. (If the list contains no elements, the new element becomes the sole element on the list.) The new element is inserted before the implicit cursor: a subsequent call to next would be unaffected, and **a subsequent call to previous would return the new element**.

`l.previous` returns the elements that you just added via `l.add("bye")`, so you'll never reach the beginning of the `List`. Hence the infinite loop.

If the `List` looks like this:

```
hai       hello
                    ^
                    |
                  cursor
```

calling `l.previous();` returns "hello" and moves the cursor back:

```
hai            hello
        ^
        |
      cursor
```

calling `l.add("bye");` adds the new element between "hai" and "hello", and before the cursor:

```
hai      bye      hello
              ^
              |
            cursor
```

so the next call to `l.previous()` will return "bye".

Therefore your loop will never reach the beginning of the `List`.

Comment: Also please go through the oracle docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#add(E)